# How to organize HTML5 images into a subfolder?

Tags: html

My directory structure looks like this:

```
 /var/www/mywebsite.co.uk/html/index.html
 /var/www/mywebsite.co.uk/images/test.jpg
```

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>My website</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <img src="../images/test.jpg">

        <h1>My Website</h1>

        Welcome to my website

    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried several other things, including moving the images folder to the same directory as the index.html file. I cannot for the life of me get the image to show, unless it is placed, without a subfolder, in the same directory as index.html.

My server is nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/mywebsite.co.uk/;

    index html/index.html;

    server_name mywebsite.co.uk www.mywebsite.co.uk;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible your document root is set to `/var/www/mywebsite.co.uk/html/`? Although it wouldn't explain why placing images to `/var/www/mywebsite.co.uk/html/images/` doesn't work.

Comment: @LáďaDurchánek I will add my config file

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using `<image src="/images/test.jpg">` and putting the images folder under html.

The /images directory will be referenced relative to your website.
Your approach with ../images/test.jpg in /index.html tries to reference a directory that is above your website and will fail with a 404 html error in the browser and in the nginx error log on the server.

Put the images and html as you wanted:
   root /var/www/mcrdatarecovery.co.uk/;  with index.html
   and images in /var/www/mcrdatarecovery.co.uk/html/images
also confirm that the files and images have the right ownership/group.

By using source="/images/test.jpg" the html url references your site url at `http://YOURWEBSITE/images/test.jpg`

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>My website</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <img src="/images/test.jpg">

        <h1>My Website</h1>

        Welcome to my website

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the suggestion

Comment: Suggest moving your images folder under the html folder and then using /images/test.jpg in your html

Comment: I've tried this, and restarted my nginx server. No improvement? It seems very odd this must surely be a trivial thing to do - I'm not trying to do something weird or unusual here am I?

Comment: make sure permissions and ownership on the /var/www/mcrdatarecovery.co.uk/images directory allow the nginx server to access /var/www/mcrdatarecovery.co.uk/images/test.jpg and that the file is accessible also with ownership and permissions.  And that index.html is /var/www/mcrdatarecovery.co.uk/index.html

Comment: Everything is owned by `www-data`, and the group is `www-data`.

Comment: Permissions are all `drwxrwxr--`

Comment: Very strange, I'm clearly doing something wrong but I don't know what it is...

Comment: if you have <base href= in your html, I suggest removing it. And use all lowercase for your file names on the server and in the links.

Comment: Ok, I've tried removing the `base href`. What should my structure look like now? I have `index.html` in the root and then a subfolder `html/images`. Should I move `images` into the root?

Comment: Ok, removing `base href` and updating the reference to the image file appears to have "fixed" the problem, although I'm not sure what the best practices should be

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.  

The way you have it organized is the most typical and certainly works for your current situation.

More info about base ref when you need it can be found at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_base_tag.htm

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `index` should be a file: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html

I would suggest moving `index.html` out of `html` to the root directory and replacing:

```
index html/index.html;
```

with

```
index index.html;
```

(or removing it completely because this is the default value).